# How can I pass data from a VC to another in Swift 3 without a segue?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3, xcode8

I have an issue passing data trough a segue because I'm using protocols to show my data. But I need to find a way to pass the data I have in a View Controller to a second one. The big issue is that I need the information in Swift 3 because the solutions that I have found are only in Onjective-C.

Well, please forget the example that I showed you. The only thing that I need to do is to pass the information inside a uilabel in my first View Controller to another uilabel in the second View Controller but without using a segue.

So I would really appreciate if somebody has a solution in Swift 3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you can't set needed data into `ViewControllerB` property? As I see in your example, you push new controller directly from `ViewControllerA`

Comment: I'm unclear what the real issue is here? Are you having difficulty converting it into Swift?

Comment: Yes, that is my issue, converting it into Swift 3!

Comment: Here is an expanded example: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-passing-data-between-controllers-in-swift--cms-27151

Comment: I follow the example exactly the way it suggests on the tutorial, but the label isn't showing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data with Navigation in Swift 3 like this: -

### Current Class

```
 let editProfile = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "editProfile") as? EditProfileVc
        if detailsModel.count != 0 {
            editProfile?.accModel = detailsModel[0] //Passing data here with the array
        }
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(editProfile!, animated: true)
```

**and target class** (here using model class variable)

```
    class EditProfileVc: BaseNotifyM, PickerDelegate {
    
        // Data Variable 
        var accModel:AccountModel? //-- Here you can use [String] or [[String: Any]] or as per you choice for data passing 

      //MARK: - Life Cycle
       override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Do some thing with your data
        print(accModel)
      }

   }
```

Comment: But using a Navigation Controller doesn't have the same effect than using a segue?

Comment: And by the way, what are you referring with detailsModel?

Comment: detailsModel is my array model that data i am passing to next VC. @Zita Noriega Estrada

Comment: Thank you very much @Anand, but this is not very helpful to me. I only need to pass the text in a UILabel from my 1st VC to another UILabel in the 2nd VC.